# How can I recover a folder deleted by SVN before it's been added to the repository

Tags: svn, version-control

I am running OS X 10.6 and using the SVN Applications "Versions", and today I made a very large mistake. I am hoping someone might be able to help me out.

I had been trying to add my new folder (4 days of work) to my repository online. This way I'd be able to distribute it to my team for moving forward. When I attempted to do this, I'd ran into trouble. I thought I'd fix the issue and versions gave me some kind of error about being obstructed. I should point out right now, I'm new to working with SVN and most of our projects are a little smaller in size and don't usually require any kind of versioning.

When I couldn't figure out the error in Versions, and with it being very difficult to find any documentation on it I thought I'd just try some troubleshooting and hope something worked. I proceeded to delete the troubled folder (thinking it'd either stay in my folder and no longer be linked to the directory or at the very least sent to my trash folder)

However this was not the case, and I've been unable to find any documentation on how to recover something like this. There's no "Undo" function (why is beyond me) and since it wouldn't add to my repository I cannot revert it either.

I'm really hoping someone here might be crafty and know a way to save all this hard work.

Thanks,
Andrew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, this is nothing to do with SVN! Its a mac issue (Versions is Mac only, right?)

As long as you've not gone writing a load of new stuff to the drive, its possible you can recover deleted files, there are a few tools you can use to [locate](http://www.cultofmac.com/how-to-undelete-files-in-mac-os-x-macrx/67472) and [un-delete](http://mackeeper.zeobit.com/mac-undelete) [them](http://subrosasoft.com/OSXSoftware/index.php?main_page=product_info&products_id=1). Google will tell you more.

Answer (score 1):

If you committed the folder to the repository before deleting it, you can restore it using `svn revert`.  Otherwise, you're SOL.  Sorry.  :\

Comment: This is what I'm afraid of. I am still in shock over the fact that the files didn't at least go to the trash folder.

Answer (score 0):

Cross your fingers and checkout your project into a temporary location.  If it exists in SVN it will show up in that checkout.